# JSON Array from Parse.com to ListView on Android

Tags: android, json, listview, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm developing a social/messaging app for Android on Android Studio, and I want to know **how to populate a ListView with a JSONArray**(friends list).

My Array (from Parse currentUser file:

```
"friends": ["friend1","friend2","friend3"]
```

Code from my activity:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class friendsTab extends Fragment {

    private ListView friendsLst;
    ParseUser current = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    JSONArray friends;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.friendsview,container,false);

        friendsLst = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.friends_list_view);
        friends = current.getJSONArray("friends");



        return v;




    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is a fully loaded question with no real work displayed on your end.

Comment: You need an adapter class to handle the data you are passing to your listView. I suggest you try reading up on these concepts. Here is a good book that explains Adapters and how to use them. You should look into it: http://www.amazon.com/Poetry-Programming-Building-Applications-Android-ebook/dp/B00W0TD6Y6

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll help you out.

Instantiate your container views and components in your Activity in onCreate(). Also create an object of your adapter class so that you can call it's constructor and use it.

```
private ListView lvFriends;
private FriendAdapter friendAdapter; // your adapter that will handle the data

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.friendsview); // <-- this is your container layout name?

   // instantiate your adapter class
   friendAdapter = new FriendAdapter();

   // instantiate your listView
   lvFriends = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friends_list_view);

   // set up your adapter
   friendAdapter = new FriendAdapter(MainActivity, parseUser); // pass your parseUser object to your adapter (or whatever information you want)
   lvFriends.setAdapter(friendAdapter); // set your adapter  
}
```

Now in your adapter class do something like the following

```
public class FriendAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private Context mContext;
   private ParseUser mParseUser;   

   // constructor
   public FriendAdapter(Context context, ParseUser parseUser) {
      this.mContext = context;
      this.mParseUser = parseUser;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
      // return the size of your friends from your parseUser object 
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
      // return the individual item from your parseUser object
   }


   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // you did not post your item view that goes into your container so I will 
      // just assume that it is just a textview

      View view = convertView;
      ViewHolder holder; // use view holder pattern
      if (view == null) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_friend, parent, false);
         holder = new ViewHolder();
         holder.tvFriendName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_friend_name);
         view.setTag(holder);

      } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
      }
      return voew;
   }

   private static class ViewHolder {
      private TextView tvFriendName;
   }

}
```

Hopefully this helps. Cheers!